# C# Panel with Grid/Overlay

Tags: c#, math, grid, overlay

Hi I would like to implement a control for a small game in c#, where the user can click on a panel and draw a path through a labyrinth. After that I want to transmit the coordinates of each "point" that was crossed on the path somewhere.

In order to do that I tried to implement some kind of grid, where each piece has the same size. I then wanted to create some kind of overlay, so that the user can click on the grid, which then turns into green and shows the way the user chose.

I made a small example below which I hope, explains what i mean by that:

[image: labyrinth]

My problem is I am not particular skilled with panels and graphics in general and hoped someone here might have some kind of source or tutorial to accomplish what I want to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're into game development, there is a [dedicated stackexchange site here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). But I'm pretty sure there also asking for tutorials will be off topic. Ask a specific question there. I'm sure you'll get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long time ago I made sth. like this using Togglebutton from Primitives :

> System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton();

Create WPF solutions with only grid

- Xaml file :

> < Grid Name="DynamicGrid" ShowGridLines="True">

- Cs file :

  ```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
  public MainWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      fillWithToggles();
  }

  public void fillWithToggles()
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
          ColumnDefinition gridCol = new ColumnDefinition();
          gridCol.Name = "Column" + i.ToString();
          DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol);
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
          RowDefinition gridRow = new RowDefinition();
          gridRow.Name = "Row" + i.ToString();
          DynamicGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow);
      }

      for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
      {
          for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
          {
              System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton();
              tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
              tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
              Grid.SetColumn(tb, x);
              Grid.SetRow(tb,y);
              DynamicGrid.Children.Add(tb);
          }                
      }
  }}
  ```

And result :

[image]

Later on you can play with borders and whole logic etc.

Answer (score 2):

Game design consists of (at least) three areas: Artistic, technical and strategical design.

I will not go into the artistic aspects of how it should look, what colors and effects it shall have.

I'll give you are a few hints on technical design, that is what platform, what controls, what methods and what data structures to use.

The third area is the hardest, in your case mostly because the others are rather simple..: The strategical design is about how to create a playable labyrinth. It is simple to create a random one, but chances are that it isn't playable. Or one that is playable but too easy. So it takes good judgment and some imagination to create good boards..

Zbig's answer gave you an example of a WPF program; my hints are using WinForms.

There are many possible ways to do it, ranging from

- drawing everything
- or using a control that supports cells
- to using separate controls for each cell.

To draw everything you would pick a control, maybe a PictureBox or a Panel and draw the current state onto it in the Paint event. for this to work you need a data structure that holds information about the board and each of its cells:

- row and column (x, y)
- set of walls (top, bottom, left, right)
- color state (empty or visited)

A control that can hold an array of cells is the DataGridview, you could use it, a good option, especially if your boards get really large.. (greater than say, 2-3000 cells)

I'll stick to the third option: Create an array of controls, one for each cell.

Here is how I would approach the technical side:

1. Use Buttons for the Cells (although other Controls would work as well) and store the game data like this:

   - The state is in the BackColor
   - The four walls are in the lower four bits of its ImageIndex
   - row and columns are in its Name or in its Tag
2. Create an ImageList that holds 16 Images, drawn dynamically: transparent and consisting of nothing but the walls, one for each bit in the index that is set.
3. Create the Buttons dynamically and map their Clicked events to one common event, where the sender parameter is used to process the click.
4. The game rule probably is simply: Paint the clicked cell if one of its four neighbors is visited and there is no wall between them. The game is finished once the exit cell is visited.

Well, I'm sure you will find the details a bit harder than a well-versed coder would; it would take him 1-2 hours at most to build the above system..

..but now we come the hard part: How to layout a playable board?!

One nice feature in games is when they offer a choice of how hard gameplay is supposed to be.

Here is a simple plan for a board creation routine:

- Start with a random board
- To make it harder sprinkle more walls over it
- Set the outer walls
- Create start and exit cells, maybe set the start cell visited
- Create one random path from start to exit
- Create some more paths between random border cells, the more you create the simpler the board should get because there will be more possible ways to transverse it.

Note that one of the hidden difficulties it that the way I have set it all up each (inner) wall really belongs to two cells, this is no problem during play but it has to be considered whenever you create a cell and/or set or delete a wall. so it will be a good idea to have a setWall(int row, int column, bool wall) function that can take care of it..

another hidden problem is how to create a random path without literally painting yourself in a corner..

Also make sure you understand that trick of using 4 bits to represent the four walls and using these bits as an index into the images of the cell walls.